# export mysql table with text block to tsv file

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

The mysql table contains a field with text block, where one cell can contain multiple text lines, for example:

> ```
> |name|text|
>
> |a|This is a
>
>  multiple-line msg|
> ```

What will be the best strategy to dump the table to a csv or tsv file so that can then be easily read by

> pandas.read_csv()

?

Comment: `pd.read_sql` and then split on delimiter.

Comment: hi @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yes, it works

Comment: HappyCoding, happy coding!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, cold speed. btw, do you want to post your answer? I can accept it as the final answer.

Comment: No worries, I only gave you the suggestion. You did all the heavy lifting, and I respect that. Post an answer to your own question with the code you used, and you can accept it after a couple of days.